# Struts2 - tiles error

Tags: java, struts2, tiles

I am working on a website using struts2 framework. I tried to run the code but then I encountered an error as below

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tiles/context/TilesRequestContextFactory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2944)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1208)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1688)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesContextFactory.<init>(JspTilesContextFactory.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tiles.context.ChainedTilesContextFactory.init(ChainedTilesContextFactory.java:84)
    at org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesContainerFactory$StrutsTilesContextFactory.init(StrutsTilesContainerFactory.java:79)
    at org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesContainerFactory.storeContainerDependencies(StrutsTilesContainerFactory.java:55)
    at org.apache.tiles.factory.TilesContainerFactory.initializeContainer(TilesContainerFactory.java:231)
    at org.apache.tiles.factory.TilesContainerFactory.createTilesContainer(TilesContainerFactory.java:198)
    at org.apache.tiles.factory.TilesContainerFactory.createContainer(TilesContainerFactory.java:163)
    at org.apache.tiles.web.startup.TilesListener.createContainer(TilesListener.java:90)
    at org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener.createContainer(StrutsTilesListener.java:70)
    at org.apache.tiles.web.startup.TilesListener.contextInitialized(TilesListener.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tiles.context.TilesRequestContextFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1718)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
    ... 31 more
```

It's a 404 error but I don't know why because I included all the tile libraries. Specifically, I am using struts2-core-2.1.6.jar and tiles-core-2.0.6.jar, build path is included and tiles listener is configured

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

More details: I am using struts-2.3.16.1 library and included

```
tiles-api-2.1.2.jar

tiles-compat-3.0.1.jar

tiles-core-2.0.6.jar

tiles-jsp-2.1.2.jar

tiles-servlet-3.0.1.jar

commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar

commons-digester-2.0.jar

struts2-tiles-plugin-2.3.16.1.jar
```

in  WEB-INF/lib

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: I'm skeptical you can arbitrarily mix tiles lib versions like this.

Comment: I don't think that I arbitrarily mix any thing because all the jar files come from strut2 library in one folder. You can download it from struts.apache.org and see.